"So ein schönes Auto wie dieses" or "Ein Auto so schön wie dieses"?
Are both "Ich habe ein Auto so schön wie dieses gesehen" and "Ich habe so ein schönes Auto wie dieses gesehen" correct?

Do you see any reasons why one of them or both could be incorrect? Simply asking "Is this correct?" is a proofreading request, and these are off-topic on German SE.

"Can I use a comparison with "so... wie..." as an attribute?"

Yes, both are correct, but they mean different things.

So(lch) ein schönes Auto wie dieses …
⇆  (Such) a beautiful car like this …


Ein Auto so schön wie dieses …
⇆  A car (that is) as beautiful as this one …


Thank you for the answer. Could you maybe share what type of phrase "so schön wie dieses" is, as an attribute to "Auto"?
